# Creating special delimiters for node.js

Tags: node.js

I am currently working on reading a pdf file and extracting the contents of a pdf file.

However, three particular (invoice value, tax, total amount payable) are coming up as one concatenated field.

So if the pdf file has invoice value as 1000, tax as 118 and amount payable as 1118, i get 1,0001181,118 as a field.

Is there any way to create a special delimiter where i check the number of digits after a comma as a rule?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very roundabout way of doing this.  The best solution I could come up with was to create a lookup table on the number of digits that a particular combination of numbers would end up with (for instance, if there are 14 digits, it means that invoice value had 5 digits, tax had 4 digits and final amount had 5 digits) and so on and so forth.

Based on the number of digits, I was then able to determine what the final amount was, then back-calculate what the tax and invoice value is.

Very crude method but i suppose it worked